# How do I disable Django per-view caching when debug is on?

Tags: django, caching

I've written a bunch of views in Django that use per-page caching. The code looks like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

@cache_page(60 * 5)
def view_page(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello world')
```

This works wonderfully, but is a pain during testing. How do I only do caching with debug off?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out django's dummy cache backend.
So for your development enviroment you should set your cache backend to `django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache`

Comment: This is a nice method, but it will still set the `Expires` header, which could be annoying in some development situations. If you're having trouble with this check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21062389/1248175) or [StephenPaulger's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5094671/1248175).

Answer (score 5):

You could conditionally decorate your view.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.conf import settings

def view_page(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello world')
if not settings.DEBUG:
    view_page = cache_page(60 * 5)(view_page)
```

or perhaps this would work.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page, never_cache
from django.conf import settings

production_cache = lambda func: cache_page(60 * 5)(func) if settings.DEBUG else never_cache(func)

@production_cache
def view_page(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello world')
```

In fact it can be done without a lambda

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page, never_cache
from django.conf import settings

production_cache = cache_page(60 * 5) if not settings.DEBUG else never_cache

@production_cache
def view_page(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello world')
```

Comment: This would mean adding the condition check to every single view that implements caching.

Comment: I have added an alternative to negate this requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Using @StephenPaulger's method, it will also prevent Django from setting the cache related headers like `Expires`. If you're working with another system that interprets these headers and keeps it's own cache as long as the date in the `Expires` header isn't reached, this can be pretty annoying while developing.

If you use `never_cache`, Django will set the `Expires` header to the current time of the request, so the document would be outdated right away.

You can create this in a separate file in your project:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.decorators.cache import (
    cache_page as django_cache_page, never_cache
)


if settings.DEBUG:
    cache_func = lambda seconds: never_cache
else:
    cache_func = django_cache_page

def cache_page(seconds):
    return cache_func(seconds)
```

Then you can import this custom `cache_page` function instead of the native Django one and use it the same way. This `if` statement would only be executed once when the module is imported.

If you have separate settings files (for development and production) you can even make it more efficient by putting the functions in the settings files. So for the development settings you would do this:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

CACHE_FUNC = lambda seconds: never_cache
```

And in the production settings you would put:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

CACHE_FUNC = cache_page
```

Then in a separate file in your project:

```
from django.conf import settings

def cache_page(seconds):
    return settings.CACHE_FUNC(seconds)
```

With this method, the `CACHE_FUNC` would be defined only once during the startup of Django. So no impact on performance, and no annoying `Expires` headers during development!